# Label return empty value in the datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datalist with one label,textbox and a button. On a button click i want a value of textbox and label, i get the value of the textbox but label is empty. How to solve this problem. Thanyou

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataListItem item in rptrItems.Items)
    {
        string quantity = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text;
        string itemName =((Label)item.FindControl("itemName")).Text;
    }
}



 <asp:DataList ID="rptrItems" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" >

                       <ItemTemplate> 
                         <div class="panel panel-info">
                           <div class="panel-heading"> Item= <asp:Label ID="itemName" runat="server"> <strong>"<%#Eval("ItemName")%>"</strong></asp:Label></div>
                           <div class="panel-body">
                              <div class="row">
                                <label class="lblQuantity"> Quantity:  </label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>  
                               </div>
                              <div class="row">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="btn-Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" /> </div>                                  
                            </div>
                          </div>
                       </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Could you post complete code?

Comment: First question - have you stepped through your code in the debugger?  That's the quickest way to figure out these kinds of issues.  In addition to that, is `itemName` the correct name for the `Label` your looking for?  Is the `Label` a child of `item`?  `FindControl` won't find nested controls.  Finally, are you sure the `Text` property on the `Label` has a value?

Comment: @Tim. Yes i use debugger to go through the value of label but it shows empty. itemName is the id of the label. Label is inside the datalist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Canavar comment use hidden field

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            rptrItems.DataSource = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item {ItemName = "Item Name",Quantity=1}
            };
            rptrItems.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataListItem item in rptrItems.Items)
        {
            string quantity = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text;
            string itemName = ((HiddenField)item.FindControl("itemName")).Value;
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

 <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="rptrItems">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="itemName" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ItemName") %>' />
    <asp:Label ID="labItemName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemName") %>' /> : 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your effort :)

Comment: @Farrukh you can up vote the answer so that it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

Only form elements post their values to server, so labels do not post their value. This is why you can't get its Text value. Try hidden input element instead.

Take a look at the HiddenField element here :

```
<asp:DataList ID="rptrItems" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" >
    <ItemTemplate> 
     <div class="panel panel-info">
       <div class="panel-heading"> 
            Item= <asp:Label ID="itemName" runat="server"> <strong>"<%#Eval("ItemName")%>"</strong></asp:Label>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="itemName" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ItemName") %>' />
       </div>
       <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <label class="lblQuantity"> Quantity:  </label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>  
           </div>
          <div class="row">
            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="btn-Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" /> </div>                                  
        </div>
      </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Access it in your code behind like that :

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataListItem item in rptrItems.Items)
    {
        string quantity = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text;
        string itemName =((HiddenField)item.FindControl("itemName")).Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about the `TextBox` field??

Comment: @Canavar.  Will you please give any example i am new to .net. Thankyou

Comment: @ajmot I dont need a textbox i want a label to show the itemName.

Comment: @Farrukh can you update your question and add your datalist markup code ? I'm going to give you an example on that code. By the way you don't need to change label.